# Array inside an object

Tags: c++, arrays, object

It's possible to create an array like this - if size is defined before arr.

```
const int size = 5;
int arr[size];
```

But it's not possible, when size and arr are inside object or struct:

```
struct A{
    A(int s) : size(s) 
    {}
    const int size;
    int arr[size]
};

A(5);
```

Why is it so? It's seems kinda illogical, because in both cases size of array is known in compilation time.

Comment: It's not possible in the class/struct because `size` is not initialized to be a value, that means that your array could have any size, which is invalid.  Use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: I know about vector or template, i just want to know, why it's not possible when (if) size is known in compilation time.

Comment: So, compiler can not detect is function argument compilation time constant or not? Or is it possible only with constexpr and c++11? Then, will my example be legal with constexpr in constructor?

Answer (score 2):

> in both cases size of array is known in compilation time.

Nope, a `const` class member can be set at run-time.

In fact, even a non-member doesn't always work:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
const int y = x;
int z[y];   //ILLEGAL
```

Just use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Well, that's true. But if it IS known in compilation time, it's possible for a simple array.

Comment: @Amomum yes, but in these cases it's not.

Comment: Question is, why if constant is known in compilation time, it's not possible for an array inside a struct, but is possible "outside"?

Comment: @Amomum it is, but in your case, the constant is not known at compile-time.

Comment: How it can be not known at compile-time if it's "5" ? Again, why compiler can distinguish "int i; int arr[i]" and "const int i=2; int arr[i]" for a simple array, but can't do the same for array inside struct?

Comment: @Amomum it can distinguish that 5 is a compile-time constant (your case). The second example is illegal - `int i; int x[i]`. If you think you're smarter than the compiler, please, do tell, what's the value of i?

Comment: Again. Compiler CAN distinguish between 'code'int i; int x[i]'code' and 'code'const int i=3; int x[i]'code', but CAN'T, if both constant and array are inside struct. My question is - why is it so?

Comment: @Amomum because a member is not a compile-time constant. :| It's not the `const` keyword that makes it constant, like I've proven in the sample. You can have `const int x = y` outside of a class and it won't work.

Comment: _because a member is not a compile-time constant._ But why T_T Even if it is, in fact, a constant.

Comment: If we imagine, that it's possible for objects of the same type to have different size, the only drawback would be - passing such object in function by value (because size would be unknown). But that's fair, we just would pass them by reference, since size still would be inside of the every object.

Answer (score 2):

> It's seems kinda illogical, because in both cases size of array is known in compilation time.

The compiler cannot distinguish between your example and this:

```
int i = std::rand(); // not a compile time constant
A a(i);
```

On the other hand, it needs to know the size of the array at compile time. Two instances of `A` cannot have different size. So the size of the array cannot depend on something that can be set at runtime.

<strike>On the other hand, C++11 provides [constexpr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#constexpr_-_Generalized_constant_expressions), which allows you to propagate compile-time constants through expressions and lets you use these to initialize arrays.</strike>

Comment: I didn't say "always known", just in this two cases.

Comment: @Amomum OK, I changed the wording. The bottom line is, pre-c++11 you are stuck, with C++11 you can use `constexpr`.

Comment: I can't see the difference. If i cannot initialize a constant with variable, why is constant inside a structure should be different?

Comment: @Amomum you *can* initialize a constant with a variable. But when you declare a class, the size or the array needs to be known at the point of declaration. The size variable is only set at the point of instantiation.

Comment: But if i initialize a constant with a variable i can't use this constant as array size. If constant is compilation time constant, then i can. The point is, that if array is inside of struct i can't do it in both cases - that's the illogical part. What is the difference?

Comment: @Amomum that is because, at the point of declaration of the array, you know the size. At the point of declaration of the class, you don't. BTW what I said about constexpr is wrong, I cannot see how it would help.

Comment: That's the illogical part. WHY at the point of class declaration i do not know the size? If, in fact, i do.

Comment: @Amomum no you don't. You know it at the point of instantiation. The fact that you can instantiate A(1) and A(42) means the size can be different for each instance. But the array can have only one size.

Comment: Waaait. Simple arrays can have any size.

Comment: @Amomum a class can have only one size... so an array data member can have only one size.

Comment: Could you please explain me, why is it so? Why arrays of one type can have different sizes and object of one type (i.e. class) can't?

Comment: @Amomum arrays of different size are different types. It is just the way the language is designed.

Comment: Well, in c++ all arrays are (afaik) just constant pointers... Still, i can't see any reason, why objects of one type can't have different size (if it's compile-time known for a start).

Comment: @Amomum no, arrays are not pointers. They may decay into pointers in some cases. But two arrays of different size are different types. As to why, well, that is the way the language is defined. Otherwise you couldn't know the stack space allocated to a function dealing with objects, for example.

Comment: @Amomum see here for an example of functions taking different array types:  http://ideone.com/I2sJaa

Comment: Got it. I had it all mixed up with plain C. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler compiles A, there is in fact no guarantee that it is a compile-time argument. It just happens to be one. I could equally do

```
int main() {
    std::cin >> i;
    A(i);
}
```

If you want to pass it a constexpr argument, you will need to use a template. Else, you will need to use a run-time container like std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::vector<int>` instead of raw arrays if you want a dynamically resizeable array.

You cannot do what you're trying to do inside the `class` or `struct` because your `size` member has no defined value.

Answer (score 0):

Because in C++ when you initialize a C-style array with a size argument, the size must be a compile-time integral constant.

Otherwise the compiler doesn't know how big to make the variable when compiling.

If you don't like this, you should be using `vector` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In second case, if you take into consideration just class definition array size is not known in compilation time.

if making such classes was allowed you could write

```
A(5);
A(6);
```

that would be objects of different size, that would break alot, for example it would not be possible to keep such objects in the same array. It would be logical to say that those objects have different type, and that would be possible if you make your class template and pass size as template parameter.

if you want to use arrays of different size use std::vector or templates.

Answer (score -1):

You need to dynamicly allocate the memory from your heap if it is not known before compile time.

int* arr = new int [size];

If you do not need the memory anymore you should delete the array.

delete[] arr;

And also as Tony said, it is better to use standart libary vectors